# What is wrong with this MySQL query syntax?

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
$db = mysql_select_db("remote"); 

if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
} 

$query = "SET @cumulative_sum := 0; 
          SELECT timestamp, 
                 @cumulative_sum := @cumulative_sum + value AS cumulative_sum 
          FROM remote.historical 
          WHERE timestamp>= CURDATE()"; 

$result = mysql_query($qry);
```

When I use this query in my HeidiSQL, it output okay...running cumulative over current day, but when I copied this code into php file, web browser outputs:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT timestamp, @cumulative_sum := @cumulative_sum + value AS
>   cumulative_sum F' at line 1

What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of executing two statements, you can alternative declare the variable in a subquery, eg.

```
SELECT  timestamp, 
        @cumulative_sum := @cumulative_sum + value AS cumulative_sum 
FROM    remote.historical, (SELECT @cumulative_sum := 0) b
WHERE timestamp>= CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons query() function do not allow multiple queries in the single statement but you can do this using `mysqli_multi_query()`.

The following link will help you: [Multiple queries in single PHP query statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php)

Comment: Thank you both very much!! You save the day!